# How can I optimize this pymc code?

Tags: pymc, pymc3

I'd like to perform inference on a simple Ising model with pymc3:

```
mu = pm.Uniform('mu', lower=0, upper=1, shape=(N,1))
energy = mu.T * W * mu + f.T * mu
logp = pm.Potential('logp', energy)
start = model.test_point
step = pm.NUTS(vars=[mu])
print 'creating NUTS took', time.time() - t0
```

However, the last `pm.NUTS` step takes 2 minutes on average to complete, and uses ~1 gigabyte of memory as well. This is for N=15, so a pretty small model. Any tips on speeding this up? It's already using very basic operations for which the second-order info should be easy to compute.

Comment: Did you try using Metropolis instead of NUTS?

Comment: Yep - same slowness.

Comment: did you have the opportunity to optimize your code ? I have a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42205123/how-to-fit-a-method-belonging-to-an-instance-with-pymc3